# Passing value inside JavaScript function and saving it into a PHP variable

Tags: php, javascript, lightbox

I am creating an application like that of Facebook photo albums having comments.

I have a webpage, which shows the pics inside an album, when a pic is clicked, a lightbox opens up, and the caption and comments on the pic will be shown. Here's the pictures.php code

```
<?php
session_start();
ob_start;
include('connection.php');
?>
<html>
<head>
<title>Photos</title>
<style type="text/css">
.wraptocenter
        {
    width: 200px;
    height: 150px;
    overflow: hidden;
        }

.wraptocenter img
        {
    vertical-align: top;
        }

.black_overlay
        {
            display: none;
            position: fixed;
            top: 0%;
            left: 0%;
            width: 100.7%;
            height: 100%;
            background-color: black;
            z-index: 1001;
            -moz-opacity: 0.8;
            opacity: .80;
            filter: alpha(opacity=80);
        }

.white_imagebox
        {
            display: none;
            position: fixed;
            top: 5%;
            left: 6%;
            width: 900px;
            height: 500px;
            padding: 0px;
            border: 0px solid #a6c25c;
            background-color: white;
            z-index: 1002;
            overflow: visible;

        }
</style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="AJAX/AjaxInsertPicComment.js"></script>     
<script>
function showpic(image_path,image_id,album_id,pic_caption)
{

    document.getElementById('AlbumDiv').style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById('fade').style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById('image').src = image_path; // this line added
    img = new Image();
    img.src = image_path;
    document.getElementById('t_albumid').value = album_id;
    document.getElementById('t_imageid').value = image_id;
    document.getElementById('t_albid').value = album_id;
    document.getElementById('t_picid').value = image_id;
    document.getElementById('albumid').value = album_id;
    document.getElementById('imageid').value = image_id;
    document.getElementById('t_imagepath').value = image_path;
    document.getElementById('caption_holder').value = pic_caption;
    if(img.width > 500 && img.height > 450)
        {
               if(img.width > img.height)
                  {

                       document.getElementById('image').style.width = "500px";
                       document.getElementById('image').style.height = 'auto';
                       delete img;
                       return false;
                  }
              else
                  {  
                       document.getElementById('image').style.height = "450px";
                       document.getElementById('image').style.width = 'auto';
                       delete img;
                       return false;
                  }            
        }
    else if(img.height > 450 && img.width < 500)
        {
              document.getElementById('image').style.height = "450px";
              delete img;
              return false;
        }     
    else if(img.height < 450 && img.width > 500)
        {
             if(img.width > img.height)
                  {
                       document.getElementById('image').style.width = "500px";
                       document.getElementById('image').style.height = 'auto';
                       delete img;
                       return false;
                  }
             else
                  {
                       document.getElementById('image').style.height = "450px";
                       document.getElementById('image').style.width = 'auto';
                       delete img;
                       return false;
                  }   
        }
    else if(img.width < 500 && img.height < 450)
        {
              if(img.width > img.height)
                  {
                       document.getElementById('image').style.width = "500px";
                       document.getElementById('image').style.height = 'auto';
                       delete img;
                       return false;
                  }
              else
                  {  
                       document.getElementById('image').style.height = "450px";
                       document.getElementById('image').style.width = 'auto';
                       delete img;
                       return false;
                  }            
        }                    
    delete img;
    alert("humm");
    return false;
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="photo_holder">
<table width="1000px" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" align="center">
<tr>
<td width="50px" align="center"/>
<td align="center" colspan="2" background="Images/header_menu.png" style="padding-right:2px;">
<?php include('header.php');?>
</td>
<td width="50px" align="center"/>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="50px" align="center" ></td>
<td width="600px" align="center">
    <?php
    $album_id=$_REQUEST['txt_albumid'];
    echo $album_id;
   /* how many columns */
    $column_number='3';
    /* html table start */
    ?>
    <div id="photo_container" align="center" width="600px">
        <table border="1px" cellspacing="5" cellpadding="0" align="left">
        <?php
        $sql="SELECT * FROM candidate_pics WHERE album_id='$album_id'";
        $result=mysql_query($sql,$con);
       // $row=mysql_fetch_array($result);
        $recordcounter=1;  /* counts the records while they are in loop */
        while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
        { 
                               /* decide if there will be new Table row (<TR>) or not ... left of division by column number is the key */
                       if($recordcounter%$column_number==1)
                           { 
                               echo "<tr>"; 
                           }
                        ?>                      
                        <td align="center" width="200px">
                        <div class="wraptocenter" align="center">
                        <?php $_SESSION['pic_id']=$row[pic_id];?>
                        <a href="javascript:void(0)" 
                        onClick="showpic('<?php echo $row[pic_path];?>','<?php echo $row[pic_id];?>',
                        '<?php echo $row[album_id];?>','<?php echo $row[pic_caption];?>')";>
                        <img src="<?php echo $row[pic_path];?>"/></a>
                        </div>
                        </td>                                   
                        <?php
                        /* decide if there will be end of table row */
                        if($recordcounter%$column_number==0)
                           { 
                                echo "</tr>"; 
                           }
                        $recordcounter++;  /* increment the counter */
        }

        if(($recordcounter%$column_number)!=1){ echo "</tr>"; }  
        ?>
        </table>
     </div>
</td>
<td width="300px" align="center" >
<div id="photo_uploader">
<form method="post" action="photo_upload.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   <table width="300px" align="center" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
       <tr>
       <td align="center" width="100px">Upload Pic::</td>
       <td align="center" width="200px">
           <input type="file" name="file" id="file" style="width: 200px;"/>
       </td> 
       </tr>
       <tr>
       <td align="center" width="100px"/>
       <td align="center" width="200px">
           <input type="submit" name="submit_pic" id="submit_pic" value="Click to upload" style="width: 200px;"/>
           <input name="txt_albumid" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $album_id;?>"/>
       </td> 
       </tr>
    </table>
</form>     
</div>
</td>
<td width="50px" align="center" ></td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>

<div id="AlbumDiv" class="white_imagebox">
<table align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="900px">
    <tr>
         <td colspan="2" height="25px">
         <div id="close">
             <a href="javascript:void(0)" 
             onclick="document.getElementById('AlbumDiv').style.display = 
             'none';document.getElementById('fade').style.display='none'">
             <img src="images/close-icon.png" style="border-style: none; border-color: inherit;
             border-width: 0px; height: 17px; width: 16px;" align="right" /></a>
         </div>
         </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
         <td width="600px" align="center">
            <table width="600px" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
               <tr>
                   <td width="50px" align="center"/>
                   <td align="center" width="500px">
                      <div id="image_holder" style="width: 500px; height: 450px; 
                      background-color:#666666;">
                      <input type="image" id="image" name="image"/>
                      </div>
                   </td>
                   <td width="50px" align="center"/>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td/>
                    <td>
                    <input type="text" id="caption_holder" name="caption_holder" 
                    style="width:500px;"/>
                    </td>
                <td/>
                </tr>
             </table>
         </td>   
         <td width="300px" align="center">
         <table width="300px" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" align="top">
               <tr>
                   <td align="center" width="100px">
                   <form method="post" action="photo_delete.php">
                   <input type="submit" name="delete" id="delete" value="Delete" 
                   class="button" style="width: 100px;"/>
                   <input type="hidden" name="t_imageid" id="t_imageid"/>
                   <input type="hidden" name="t_imagepath" id="t_imagepath"/>
                   <input type="hidden" name="t_albumid" id="t_albumid"/>
                   </form>
                   </td>
                   <td align="center" width="100px">
                   <form>
                   <input type="button" name="edit" id="edit" value="Edit" class="button"
                   style="width: 100px;" 
                   onclick="document.getElementById('pic_caption').style.visibility = 'visible'; 
                   document.getElementById('enter_caption').style.visibility = 'visible';"/>
                   </form>
                   </td>
                   <td align="center" width="100px">
                   <form method="post" action="">
                   <input type="submit" name="cover_pic" id="cover_pic" value="Set CoverPic" class="button"
                   style="width: 100px;"/>
                   <input type="hidden" name="t_albumname" id="t_albumname"/>
                   <input type="hidden" name="t_imagename" id="t_imagename"/>
                   </form>
                   </td>   
               </tr>
               <tr>
                  <td height="100px" colspan="3">
                  <form method="post" action="photo_edit.php">
                  <input type="text" name="pic_caption" id="pic_caption" style="visibility:hidden;"/>
                  <input type="submit" name="enter_caption" id="enter_caption" style="visibility:hidden;"/>
                  <input type="hidden" name="t_picid" id="t_picid"/>
                  <input type="hidden" name="t_albid" id="t_albid"/>
                  </form>
                  </td>   
               </tr>
               <tr>
                   <td height="300px" colspan="3">
                   <div id="" style="overflow-y:scroll; height:300px;">
                      <table width="282px" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" 
                      align="center">
                          <tr>
                          <td>
                              <?php
                               echo $_SESSION[pic_id];?>
                              <div id="message_report">
                              </div>
                          </td>
                          </tr>
                          <tr>
                          <td>
                              <form method="post" action=
                              "javascript:get(document.getElementById('pic_comment_form'));" name=
                              "pic_comment_form" id="pic_comment_form">
                              <table width="280px" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" 
                              align="center" >
                              <tr>
                              <td width="100px">
                              <input type="text" name="comment" id="comment" style="width:100px"/>
                              </td>
                              <td width="80px"/>
                              <td width="100px">
                              <input type="submit" name="comment_enter" id="comment_enter" style="width:100px"/>
                              </td>
                              <tr>
                              <td>
                              <input type="hidden" name="albumid" id="albumid"/></td>
                              <td>
                              <input type="hidden" name="imageid" id="imageid"/></td>
                              <td>
                              <input type="hidden" name="user" id="user" 
                              value="<?php echo $_SESSION[logged_user];?>"/></td>
                              </tr>
                              </table>
                              </form>
                          </td>
                          </tr>
                      </table> 

                   </div>
                   </td>
               </tr>
         </table>
         </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</div>

<div id="fade" class="black_overlay">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

The code

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" 
                        onClick="showpic('<?php echo $row[pic_path];?>','<?php echo $row[pic_id];?>',
                        '<?php echo $row[album_id];?>','<?php echo $row[pic_caption];?>')";>
                        <img src="<?php echo $row[pic_path];?>"/></a>
```

pass the album_id, pic_id to the javascript functions which is then passed to the objects in the lightbox such as id="t_albumid", id="t_imageid"

I need to write a SQL query in the lightbox like this:

```
SELECT * FROM  candidate_pics_comment WHERE pic_id='$VariableHavingPicId
```

but for this I must use the variable in the JavaScript `image_id` and pass it again to the lightbox div in the JavaScript. The code:

```
document.getElementById('t_imageid').value = image_id;
```

assigns the object, the value as image_id, but how can we assign the image_id to a php variable so that I can use it in the sql query?

I mean in the JavaScript can it be something like this:

```
function showpic(image_path,image_id,album_id,pic_caption)
{
    <?php
    $var = //assign the value image_id;?>
    // rest of the code here;
}
```

I know it's not possible, but is there some trick to achieve this?

Moreover as I was experimenting, I did something like this:

```
function showpic(image_path,image_id,album_id,pic_caption)
{
    <?php
    $_SESSION[pic_id]="hmmm";?>
    //rest codes;
}
```

Then when I used `echo $_SESSION[pic_id]` in php script, it displayed `hmmm`

So I was thinking can it be done something like this?

```
function showpic(image_path,image_id,album_id,pic_caption)
    {
        <?php
        $_SESSION[pic_id]=//assign image_id to session variable;?>
        //rest codes;
    }
```

Besides I used AJAX application, but I saw that AJAX returns the response to the objects innerHTML, how ca it be stored in a php variable?

### Update

My question is that, I am passing values from this

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" 
                        onClick="showpic('<?php echo $row[pic_path];?>','<?php echo $row[pic_id];?>',
                        '<?php echo $row[album_id];?>','<?php echo $row[pic_caption];?>')";>
                        <img src="<?php echo $row[pic_path];?>"/></a>
```

to the JavaScript fiunction

```
function showpic(image_path,image_id,album_id,pic_caption)
```

Now how can I assign image_id to a PHP variable which I can use in the div `AlbumDiv` which is used for the lightbox. If that not possible how can a session variable be assign the value of image_id, is it possible inside the JavaScript function?

Comment: **tl;dr** what is your question?

Answer (score 0):

ajax is the only option to get something from JavaScript to PHP.

If you are using jQuery then take a look at the docs [here](http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/)

Otherwise I recommend you use a Library like jQuery or jQuery itself